# What does this error mean in Scheme: "and: bad syntax in: and"?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am getting the following error "and: bad syntax in: and":

```
(define test (lambda(list1 a b c d)
    (cond (null? list1)
       (and (eqv? a b) (eqv? c d))
       (two-subsets (cdr list1) a b c d))))

(test '(1 2 3 4) 0 0 0 0)
```

Essentially I am trying to make the following recursive call as a base case (equivalent in java):

```
return (a == b && c == d);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a == b && c == d` is `(and (eqv? a b) (eqv? c d))`, however you are using `cond` wrong. The right way is:

```
(cond
  (predicate-expression consequence-expression ...)
  ...
  (else alternative-expression ...))
```

Your attempts look like this:

```
(cond
  (null? list1)
  (and (eqv? a b) (eqv? c d))
  (two-subsets (cdr list1) a b c d))))
```

That makes `null?` the predicate and `list1` the consequent. Since `null?` is a procedure it cannot be `#f` and thus your `cond` should return `list1` always. Because `and` is not allowed to be evaluated on its own and it is a macro you get a compile time error.

I have no idea what you are trying to do with that `cond` since if I add parentheses I get this:

```
(cond
  ((null? list1) #t)
  ((and (eqv? a b) (eqv? c d)) #t)
  (else (two-subsets (cdr list1) a b c d))))))
```

This is based on that a `cond` terms with no consequences return their true value and both `null?` and `eqv?` return `#t` when it's not `#f`. It also clear that this can be replaced with `#t` since that is always the result no matter what the arguments are.

`cond` is not a primitive and it just translated your code to `if`. Just for fun here is what your original `cond` gets translated to:

```
(if null? 
    list1
    (if and
        (begin
          (eqv? a b)  ; dead code
          (eqv? c d))
        (if two-subsets
            (begin
              (cdr list1) ; dead code  
              a           ; dead code 
              b           ; dead code
              c           ; dead code
              d)
            'undefined-return-value))) ; no  else clause
```